# A work rate problem

Tags: linear-algebra

**Micheal paints  $\frac{1}{p}$ of a building in 20 mins,  what fraction of the same bulding can Hena paints in 20 mins, if they paint the building in an hour, working together.**

**Answer options:**

> $\frac{1}{3p}$
>
> $\frac{3p}{p}$-3
>
> $\frac{p-3}{3p}$

I have done in this way:
The workrate of micheal is: $\frac{3}{p}$ in an hour. 
therefore Hena will do $p-\frac{3}{p}$ in an hour.
Hence in 20 mins Hena will do, $\frac{p-\frac{3}{p}}{3}$= $\frac{p}{3}-\frac{1}{p}$

But this is not appeared in the answer list. Where is my error?

Comment: Hena will do $1 - \frac{3}{p}$ in an hour (one whole building, minus what Michael does). Dividing by $3$, I still can't make it match any of the options, though.

Comment: the last two options don't appear to be fully simplified: $\frac{3p}{p} - 3 = 0$ and $p-\frac{3}{3p} = \frac{p^2-1}{p}$

Comment: answer is given 3. So answer will be: $$\frac{1}{3}-\frac{3}{3p}$$ in 20 mins wihtout simplication?

Comment: Yes, that's the answer if you don't simplify.