# Work and Combined Rates problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It takes Nicolai one and a half hours to paint the walls of a room and two hours to paint the ceiling. Elena needs exactly one hour to paint the walls of the same room and one hour to paint the ceiling. If Nicolai and Elena work together, what is the shortest possible time in minutes in which they can paint the walls and the ceiling of that room?

Comment: Welcome to the website. What have you tried?

Comment: I would approach this by assigning each of the persons an "effective work-ability" for wall and ceilings. In addition, both walls and ceilings have a "required work amount" parameter, so that the time it takes to finish the task is equal to requred work parameter divided by the (sum of) work-ability.

Comment: You may want to first find what fraction of walls each person can do in **one hour** (and also for ceiling).

Comment: Similar problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534436/a-work-rate-problem

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is for Elena to paint the ceiling.
After that hour, 1/3 of the room remains unpainted.

E works at 1 rm/hr;  N works at 2/3 rm/hr.
In t minutes t/60 + 2t/180 rooms get painted by both.
Solve t/60 + 2t/180 = 1/3 for t.
Answer is 60 + t.